# How reload src element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to force browser reload single element of the page ('src' in my case, or 'div', no matter)?
Using this code:

```
$("div#imgAppendHere").html("<img id=\"img\" src=\"/photos/" + recipe.id + ".png\" height=\"60px\"/>");
```

It changes page source, but not reload changed element. How to do it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? The code should add an image to the element when that code is executed. Is the image supposed to be changing on the server and it is not picking up the new image?

Comment: If you mean make it reload a resource at the same url that has changed, ie a new image was generated, just add a unique query parameter at the end of the src url, like `recipe.jpg?_=148858838`

Comment: It does, source of page changes, but view of page stays as was, not reload changed element

Comment: Still have no clue what you mean "the source of page changes". Maybe you should show more code. A smaller example that shows the problem.

Comment: html page changes after script executed, but image on the page stays same as was before executing script

Answer (score 1):

Patrick Evans, you right, that hack is works.
So my code is:

```
var someRandQuery = "?" + (Math.random()*100000);
$("#imgAppendHere").html("<img id=\"img\" src=\"/photos/" + recipeId + ".png" + someRandQuery + "\" height=\"60px\"/>");
```